# Arrays: Out of Bounds Computation

Tags: c, arrays

This program when run on CodeBlocks v13.12 with GCC v4.8.1 gives the output: `2, 0`. Can someone please explain why or how?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( )
{
    int function [ 2 ] [ 3 ] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4 } }, i = 1, j = 1;
    function [ i + 1 ] [ j ] = function [ j ] [ i + 1 ];    // Assignment Statement
    printf ( "%d, %d", function [ i ] [ j ], function [ j ] [ i + 1 ] );

    return 0;
}
```

I've also noticed that in the `Assignment Statement`, the LHS of the expression is always assigned to the variable `i`. So, for example, if the statement was changed as:

```
function [ i + 1 ] [ j ] = 100;    // Assignment Statement
```

The value of `i` would be `100`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function [ i + 1 ] [ j ]
```

Accessing array out of bound will lead to undefined behavior.

`function [ 2 ]` is array out of bound access.

Comment: Thanks Gopi, can you help with the second part of the question ie. why is the value of 'i' changing?

Comment: The answer already dealt with that. **Undefined behavior** means that anything can happen. Why don't you stop writing off the end of your array? Why did you think it would be a good idea to do that?

Comment: @DMehta When we say undefined behavior. We can't explain the results from it.

Comment: I'm experimenting with the memory locations.

Comment: @DMehta Good !! experiment but take care that you don't lead to UB with your experiments and expect explanation for the same

Comment: @DMehta Once you have UB in your code you are bound to get erroneous results

Comment: @Gopi: Got it. I was sure the printf statement would give erroneous results but I wasn't sure why the value of 'i' would be updated. But thanks anyway.